# How do I know if I'm working on a Virtual Machine or not?

Tags: windows, virtualization, virtual-machines

Is there a way to know if the Windows machine I'm working on is virtual or physical?
(I'm connecting with RDP to the machine. If it's a virtual machine it is working and handled by VMWare).

Comment: see also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779723/determine-when-running-in-a-virtual-machine

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If it's Windows, just have a look at the hardware screens. It'll have a billion and five VMWare-branded virtual devices.

Comment: Agreed. Since the OP mentioned RDP, it's most likely Windows, so there you go.

Comment: +1 for not assuming it's Linux like I did

Comment: Looking at drivers is also works for linux.  lsmod would probably return the information that you need.

Comment: @Seamus: True enough!

Comment: Correction: A billion and six.

Answer (score 79):

In the CMD window type:

```
SYSTEMINFO
```

You will find a line with the following text (or similar):

```
System Manufacturer:       VMware, Inc.
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
```

Comment: If Hyper V is used you get: System Manufacturer:       Microsoft Corporation
System Model:              Virtual Machine

Comment: There is a list of values for different VM implementations here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89718

Answer (score 21):

If it's handled by VMware, it isn't too difficult at the present moment. This could change in the future.

```
# dmidecode -s system-manufacturer
VMware, Inc.
```

Comment: I get 'dmidecode' is not recognized as an internal or external command on both Windows 7 and 10 ESXi 6.0 VMs.

Comment: [`dmidecode`](https://www.tecmint.com/how-to-get-hardware-information-with-dmidecode-command-on-linux/) is a linux command used to get information about the hardware. It does not work on Windows.

Comment: for `linux` OS this is the best option to detect hardware vs virtual machine..

Comment: For KVM use: `dmidecode -s system-product-name`

Answer (score 19):

In Linux you can also use "virt-what". "[virt-what - detect if we are running in a virtual machine](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/)".

Answer (score 10):

On Windows, from CMD:

```
Systeminfo | findstr /i model
```

returns something like:

```
System Model:              VMware Virtual Platform
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5 GenuineInt
```

Answer (score 10):

On Linux, run this:

```
$ dmesg |grep -i hypervisor
 Hypervisor detected: KVM
```

Comment: for linux you type `dmesg |grep DMI` Virtual Machines: [root@myhost ~]# dmesg |grep DMI<br> DMI 2.3 present. DMI: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090006 05/23/2012 [root@myhost ~]# dmesg |grep -i virtual DMI: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090006 05/23/2012 Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input1 scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access Msft Virtual Disk 1.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 input: Microsoft Vmbus HID-compliant Mouse as /devices/virtual/input/input4 Physical: [root@backdev1

Comment: this worked for me. `dmidecode` returned `permission denied !`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Windows, as [castrocra](https://serverfault.com/users/135102/castrocra) says, you can run the `systeminfo` command *from inside a cmd shell*, then look for the "BIOS Version".

These are probably *real* machines:

```
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. A03, 06/12/2010
BIOS Version:              Phoenix Technologies, LTD MS7254 1.08, 08/03/2007
```

This, on the other hand, is almost certainly a *virtual* machine:

```
BIOS Version:              VMware, Inc. VMW71.00V.0.B64.1201040214, 04/01/2012
```

Comment: Modern hypervisors can supply arbitrary strings here, making this a not very reliable check.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't reliable. I'm running a virtual machine but my BIOS is showing as: "Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 16/08/2013"

Comment: VMWare with `Phoenix Technologies LTD 6.00, 9/17/2015`

Answer (score 4):

It has been answered, but FWIW you can do this in powershell:

```
gwmi -q "select * from win32_computersystem"
```

The "Manufacturer" will be "Microsoft Corporation" and the "Model" will be "Virtual Machine" if it's a virtual machine, or it should display regular manufacturer details if not, e.g. "Dell Inc." and "PowerEdge R210 II" respectively.

Comment: Funny. _My_ Windows VM says the Manufacturer and Model are both "Bochs".

Comment: Or in cmd: `wmic computersystem get manufacturer | find "VMware" && echo In VMWare || echo Not in VMWare`. It's faster than `systeminfo`-based solutions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Are you using VMs? Which platform - HyperV, VMWare or something else?  Seems like the VM is probably being run in a Bochs emulator or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux if you prefer to look under `/proc` try

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags | grep hypervisor
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler - wmic /node: bios get serialnumber

Anything that returns a Dell-style serial number is physical.

It will also return "VMware-42 22 26 a8 dd 6e e3 b3-2e 03 fc 2c 92 ae 2e 89", if it's a virtual machine.

Comment: Sadly, this is not working all the time. Our ESXi servers are running a DELL VMware Image, and all VMs claim to be a Dell hardware server via WMI. The serial number is the DELL service tag.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1005436) which describes the official way to do so:

For Windows:

Click Start > Run.
Type msinfo32 and press Enter.
In the right pane, look for System Manufacturer for 'VMware, Inc.'

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ["Host Detection"](http://www.codegurus.be/codegurus/Programming/virtualpc&vmware_en.htm) program.

Comment: This link is broken as of 2019. I found [this page](http://www.codegurus.be/Programming/c++_en.htm) on the site that links to the program page, but *that* link is also broken.

Comment: Seems like the last working cached page of this was back in 2007: http://web.archive.org/web/20070401065556/http://www.codegurus.be/codegurus/Programming/virtualpc&vmware_en.htm

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Unix VM, use [imvirt](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html). It's a Perl script that detects VMWare, Xen, and several others.

Comment: He's speaking about a Windows virtual machine, not a Unix one

Answer (score 0):

One (relatively) simple way to detect key virtualization information is via WMI / WBEM.  You can use the root\CIM2 namespace and access  the Baseboard class (full of interesting BIOS information) to get a description of the "physical" system.  This class often includes information about the motherboard and chassis  - manufacture, model, serial number, other.

Run the following command from a command prompt or PowerShell session:

```
wmic baseboard get manufacturer, product, Serialnumber, version
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same question and found that there are a lot of processes running with "VM" in the name, for example VMWareTray.exe

Comment: Yes, but only if the VMware tools package is installed.

Answer (score -2):

nbtstat -a 
The outcome will tell you as VMs have a speecific prefix which is 00-50-56-XX-XX-XX. There is also another prefix it uses but I can not remember at the top of my head but I recall Vcenter uses 00-50-56-XX-XX-XX so this ios the one I check only.

I think this is the best way, personally.

Comment: ...except for when someone manually sets the MAC address to something else

Comment: or clones it from existing hardware in a P-V situation